# Javascript while loop not rendering html in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

**EDIT:** ( SEE ANSWER BELOW )

I've been a long time viewer of stackoverflow but my first question today since I didn't found any answer anywhere... I have a strange behavior with my javascript code. I've tried a lot of different way but never been able to correct the problem.  What I want is to collapse and expand some element when I click on a button... Normally it would be simple and it's working In Chrome but not in IE8.

- There is no error message
- He enter the loop but do not had the class or the toggle to my element.
- here is my javascript code:

  ```
  function collapseClick(obj) {
    var group = $(obj).attr('data-maingroup');
    console.log("collapseClick on group:" + group);
    console.log("obj class before:" + $(obj).attr('class'));


    if ($(obj).hasClass("toggleExpand")) {
      $(obj).addClass("toggleMinus");
      $(obj).removeClass("toggleExpand");

    } else {
      $(obj).removeClass("toggleMinus");
      $(obj).addClass("toggleExpand");
    }
    console.log("obj class after:" + $(obj).attr('class'));


  $('div[data-group="' + group + '"]').each(function (index, item) {
       console.log("div loop for group:" + group + " index:" + index);
       $(this).toggle();
   });
  ```

  }

here is my Html that is rendered:

```
<div id="chart">
   <div class="leftPart">
     <div class="header">name</div>
     <div class="item parent">
       <a id="collapse_Integrated_Planning" onclick="collapseClick(this);return false;" style="float:left;" class="leftcollapse toggleMinus" data-maingroup="Integrated Planning"></a>Integrated Planning
     </div>
    <div class="item child gantShow" data-group="Integrated Planning">John Smith</div>
    <div class="item child gantShow" data-group="Integrated Planning">Alex Smith</div>    
  </div>
  <div class="gantMainControl" id="gantControl">
     <div class="header">
        <div class="headerRow"> 
           <div class="headerRowYear" id="headerYear">
               <div class="headerCellYear" style="width:1499.5983985355874px">2013</div>
          </div>
        </div>
   <div class="headerRow">
       <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:126.42890508110469px">January</div>   
       <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:114.1938497506752px">February</div>
       <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:126.42890508110469px">March</div>
       <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:122.35055330429486px">April</div><div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:126.42890508110469px">May</div>
       <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:122.35055330429486px">June</div>
       <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:126.42890508110469px">July</div><div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:126.42890508110469px">August</div>
       <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:122.35055330429486px">September</div>
       <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:126.42890508110469px">October</div>
       <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:122.35055330429486px">November</div>
       <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:126.42890508110469px">December</div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
     <div class="timelineContainer" style="width: 1503px;"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="container gantShow" data-group="Integrated Planning">
     <div class="timelineContainer child" style="width: 1503px;">
        <div class="timeline" style="width:722.9598440425635px;margin-left:772.560202716214px" title="2013/07/08 - 2013/12/31&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;Integrated Planning" onclick="onTimelineClick(this)" data-id="159c5c97-c135-4906-970c-e4d58f647c41" data-startdate="2013/07/08">100%</div>
        </div>
     </div>
 <div class="container gantShow" data-group="Integrated Planning">
     <div class="timelineContainer child" style="width: 1503px;">
         <div class="timeline" style="width:949.2691917671041px;margin-left:546.2508549916735px" title="2013/05/14 - 2013/12/31&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;Integrated Planning" onclick="onTimelineClick(this)" data-id="5c3756b1-0674-4bfc-b6ce-fa765db63eed" data-startdate="2013/05/14">100%</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Here is my console log:

LOG: collapseClick on group:Integrated Planning
LOG: obj class before:leftcollapse toggleMinus
LOG: obj class after:leftcollapse toggleExpand
LOG: div loop for group:Integrated Planning index:0
LOG: div loop for group:Integrated Planning index:1
LOG: div loop for group:Integrated Planning index:2
LOG: div loop for group:Integrated Planning index:3

I really need help this IE8 problem begin to annoyed me a lot...

**ANSWER:**
I've found the answer to my question.

The problem was related with how chrome and IE handle the resize event.

I had another javascript function that was called on the resize of the browser (

```
   $(window).resize(function () {
        console.log("resize");
        config.zoomLevel = ($(window).width() - 200) / 421.739; //magic formula to know how many pixel is entering in the screen for the chart.
        createGantControl(('#' + mainControlId), config);
    });
```

).

This function was regenerating my graph.

- when you change css value, Chrome doesn't call the resize event.
- BUT when you change css value in IE, IE recall the resize so my graph was always rerender.

Hope it can help in the futur!

 -Jeff

Comment: Please indent your html if you want some help

Comment: which version of jquery do you use ? IE8 is not supported by jquery 2.x you have to install 1.10 instead.

Comment: Actually I used the version 1.9 and it was not related to jquery.

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it as an answer below, rather than editing the question. Then mark your answer as "accepted". This will help others who may be searching for a similar issue.

Comment: I can't my account is new... I have to wait 8 hours... I will post as an answer when I will be able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer to my question.

The problem was related with how Chrome and IE handle the `resize` event.

I had another JavaScript function that was called on the resize of the browser:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
     console.log("resize");
     //magic formula to know how many pixel is entering in the screen for the chart
     config.zoomLevel = ($(window).width() - 200) / 421.739;
     createGantControl(('#' + mainControlId), config);
});
```

This function was regenerating my graph.

- When you change CSS value, Chrome doesn't call the `resize` event.
- BUT when you change CSS value in IE, IE recalls the `resize` event so my graph was always rerender.